# Generating table with jquery row by row?

Tags: jquery

In the example HTML file below, `test.htm`, I have a hardcoded table, which I'm trying to (re-)generate with jQuery; so far, I just tried to reconstruct the two header rows, but unfortunately it doesn't work - this is what I get in Firefox:

[image: tblffox]

Essentially, I'm trying to do something like this in jQuery:

```js
var row1 = $("#tblGen").append($('<tr>'));
row1.append( $('<th>').attr("rowspan","2").text('AA'));
...
var row2 = $("#tblGen").append($('<tr>'));
...
var tbody = $("#tblGen").append($('<tbody>'));
...
```

... meaning, I try to create row, then populate it, then another row, then `tbody` - but what I'm getting is `tbody` first with two empty `tr`s, and then `th`s outside of a `tr`.

So I'm obviously doing something wrong - what am I doing wrong, and how could I generate the example table with jQuery (just the first two header rows would be enough, I guess)?

The file `test.htm`:

```htm
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
.tblTest,
.tblTest tr th,
.tblTest tr td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  font: 12px helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
}
.tblTest tr th {
  background-color: #BBB;
}
.tdh { border-width: 2px; } /* NOWORK */
  </style>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function GenerateTable() {
  $("#tblGen").html("");
  // compose the table headers (two rows)
  var numcolspan=3;
  var row1 = $("#tblGen").append($('<tr>'));
  row1.append( $('<th>').attr("rowspan","2").text('AA'));
  row1.append( $('<th>').attr("colspan",numcolspan).text('BB') );
  row1.append( $('<th>').attr("colspan",numcolspan).text('CC') );
  row1.append( $('<th>').attr("colspan",numcolspan).text('DD') );
  var row2 = $("#tblGen").append($('<tr>'));
  for(var ix=0; ix<3; ix++) { // loop three times
    row1.append( $('<th>').text('EE') );
    row1.append( $('<th>').text('FF') );
    row1.append( $('<th>').text('GG') );
  }
  var tbody = $("#tblGen").append($('<tbody>'));
}
ondocready = function() {
  GenerateTable();
}
$(document).ready(ondocready);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Table I want to create:</h2>

<table id="tblTested" class="tblTest">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">AA</th>
    <th colspan="3" class="tdh">BB</th>
    <th colspan="3" class="tdh">CC</th>
    <th colspan="3" class="tdh">DD</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>EE</th>
    <th>FF</th>
    <th>GG</th>
    <th>EE</th>
    <th>FF</th>
    <th>GG</th>
    <th>EE</th>
    <th>FF</th>
    <th>GG</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="TestTBody">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

  <h2>Generated:</h2>
  <div id="divholder">
    <table id="tblGen" class="tblTest">
    </table>
  </div> <!-- divholder -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to first compile the HTML string and then append to DOM.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - what do you mean by "first compile the HTML string"? Can you post an answer with an example?

Comment: The DOM modification is costly... When you insert a `<tag>`, it becomes complete.

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar, but now I understand you even less - I understand "*The DOM modification is costly*", but I don't understand "*When you insert a <tag>, it becomes complete.*"; what becomes complete, the DOM? If so, how does that relate to insertion of rows?

Comment: Ha ha... Sorry for being unclear. Let's say, you have to build something like this: `<p><b>Hello <a href="#">link</a></b></p>`. You cannot give something like: `$(el).append("<p>"); $(el).append("<b>"); $(el).append("<a href='#'>"); $(el).append("link");` - This will be totally invalid. Did you understand?

Comment: General solution as follows: 1. create a <tbody> without appending to table. 2. Loop rows: append each row to tbody (not to table). 3 append tbody created in step 1 to table#tblGen

Comment: @PraveenKumar - thanks, I understand better now; I think `:)` - as far as I can see, you're pointing to the fact that if I append to `$(el)`, then I won't get the nesting as in your example, which makes sense. But then, I *think* I am doing the equivalent of `var myp = $(el).append("<p>"); var myb = myp.append("<b>"); ...` etc, which I think in terms of nesting would work? Or did I understand wrong again?

Comment: Thanks @Geert-Jan - however, my initial problem here is to generate the header rows, which in principle should be outside `tbody`, shouldn't they?

Comment: @sdbbs `$(el).append("<p>");` returns `el` and not `<p>`. That's the very big mistake.

Comment: Thank you @PraveenKumar - I finally see what my mistake is; appreciate it! (Also, I just realized that `var row1 = $("#tblGen").append($('<tr>'));` automatically inserts a `tbody` - not sure if this is jquery or Firefox doing it)

Comment: @sdbbs Do you want me to add it as an answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - please do, I think it was quite critical I didn't understand that; will be good for it to be emphasized as an answer...

Comment: @sdbbs Updated my answer. `:)` Thanks for giving me this chance to explain you and clarify. `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems I could see is, you cannot append partial HTMLs. You need to compile the HTML and then `append` or change the `innerHTML` (using `.html()` or something). Consider the below code:

```
<p><b>Hello <a href="#">link</a></b></p>
```

If you are doing it this way, the results will be crazy:

```
$(el).append("<p>");
$(el).append("<b>");
$(el).append("<a href='#'>");
$(el).append("link");
$(el).append("</a>");
$(el).append("</b>");
$(el).append("</p>");
```

The above code will give you totally undesired results. You need to do it in a different way:

```
html = "<p>";
html += "<b>";
html += "<a href='#'>";
html += "link";
html += "</a>";
html += "</b>";
html += "</p>";
$(el).append(html);
```

The other **critical issue** is that, when you are using something like:

```
$(el).append("<p>");
```

The above returns `$(el)` as a jQuery object and not `<p>`. I guess that's the fundamental problem with your code.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated, - note also [@lolka_bolka](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38323960/6197439)'s answer, where (I think) he demonstrates the "compile the HTML" approach mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @sdbbs Yes yes... I know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short descritption with [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7venmgof/). Push the button once, and check the `DOM`. This is just an example.

**JS**

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var $tbody = $('<tbody/>');
  var $row1 = $('<tr/>');
  var $cell = $('<th/>');
  $cell.attr('rowspan', '2').text('AA');
  $("#tblGen").append($tbody.append($row1.append($cell)));
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Click</button>
<table id="tblGen" class="tblTest"></table>
```

The problem is when you do this:

```
var row1 = $("#tblGen").append($('<tr>'));
```

then `row1` will not be the row, but the table itself. This is why your elements are appended the table.

Comment: Many thanks, @lolka_bolka, that is a very helpful example indeed.